# VB Copy File if Regex matches

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm working on the following code. It's run on a text file which has a list of partial names on it. It needs to loop through the text file select each name one by one then loop through a directory and find that file with the partial match and copy it to a different subfolder.

I changed the code to use Directory.GetFiles. This finds the file using the wild card but the System.IO.File.Exists and .Copy do not work with the sFileToFind and MoveWithParth variables. I'm not sure if I'm even on the right path with this.

Thank you for all your help and patience
Maxine

code:

```
Dim sFileToFind As String
Dim MoveLocation As String
Dim location As String
Dim MoveWithPath As String
Dim File As String



location = txtFolderPath.Text
MoveLocation = txtMovePath.Text

Dim FILE_NAME As String
FILE_NAME = txtFileName.Text

Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)

Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
File = objReader.ReadLine()
sFileToFind = location & "\" & File & "*.*"
MoveWithPath = MoveLocation & "\" & File & "*.*"

Dim paths() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(location, File & "*.*")
If paths.Length > 0 Then
If System.IO.File.Exists(sFileToFind) = True Then
System.IO.File.Copy(sFileToFind, MoveWithPath)
End If
End If

Loop

MsgBox("Files have been moved")
Me.Close()
```

Example file names:

```
FullFileName.doc
File.txt
Name.sgm
```

Example of file with list of names:

```
FileName
File.txt
Name
```

Comment: Regex is not glob, you can't use `*` as the first pattern, it creates an invalid pattern. And that is not how you negate a match. You might check if there is no match with `If Not Regex.IsMatch(File, "your_pattern")...`

Comment: What if I use "\w.+" & Filename & "\w.+"$ @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: You are trying to find a file inside a directory, which contains the given partial file name? If so, a Regex alone is not going to accomplish that. You would need to loop through the directory files to find a match first.

Comment: @Meta-Knight that is exactly what I need to do. Loop through the directory and find the file name that has a partial match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, searchPattern)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_) to get a list of files that match a pattern.

searchPattern can be `"*" & File & "*"`, but dirPath must be a path to the base directory where your files are located.

I would strongly advice to validate `File` in advance to make sure that it doesn't contain any special chars like * and ? , and Trim it.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? @battlmonstr

Comment: I updated my code with your suggestions but still having problems with the copying files. @battlmonstr

Comment: The code is almost right. 1) You only need stars in the searchPattern, not in other places. 2) sFileToFind = paths.First 3) Instead of "*.*" you could use `"*" & File & "*"` or `String.Format("*{0}*", File)`, this matches with your examples.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer. Since I couldn't use System.IO.File.Exists(sFileToFind) because it wouldn't take regular expressions I focussed on "IO.Directory.GetFiles"

Here's my code. Take a look and let me know if it could be better written.

```
Dim sFileToFind As String
Dim MoveLocation As String
Dim location As String
Dim MoveWithPath As String
Dim File As String
Dim LogFile As FileStream = File.Create(MoveLocation & "\" & Log & ".txt")


location = txtFolderPath.Text
MoveLocation = txtMovePath.Text

Dim FILE_NAME As String
FILE_NAME = txtFileName.Text

Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)

Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
File = objReader.ReadLine()
sFileToFind = location & "\" & File & "*.*"
Dim paths() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(location, "*" & File & "*.*")
    For Each pathAndFileName As String In paths
        If System.IO.File.Exists(pathAndFileName) = True Then
            Dim sReg As String() = pathAndFileName.Split(New Char() {"\"c})
            Dim sRegLast As String = pathAndFileName.Substring(pathAndFileName.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
            MoveWithPath = MoveLocation & "\" & sRegLast
            System.IO.File.Copy(pathAndFileName, MoveWithPath)
        Else
            'Write to output file. File not found
            LogFile = MoveLocation & "\" & Log & ".txt"
        End If
    Next

Loop

MsgBox("Files have been moved")
Me.Close()
```

Comment: You should remove File.Exists check, you know files exist because you just retrieved them from the directory ;-)
You should also remove sReg variable which is unused.

Comment: Also you could accept @battlmonstr answer since he pointed to the right solution.